# to output CSV file for pop-up window using C# in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, popup

I try to output CSV file in pop-up window. I can output CSV in main window, but not in pop-up.
I use same code. For example; I use a form to output CSV file. When this form is main window, can output CSV file. When I use this form as a pop-up, it can't output. How can I do?

It is my CSV output function:

```
public void OutputCSV(DataTable dtValue, string strFilename)
{

        if (TextUtility.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilename))
        {
            throw new I01Exception(Enums.ExType.System, "9909_35");
        }

        DataTable dt = dtValue;
        StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        string strCh = ",";

        //項目名
        for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            sb.Append("\"" + dt.Columns[k].Caption + "\"" + strCh);
        }
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

        //データ
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Empty);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("\"" + row[i].ToString() + "\"" + strCh);
            }
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strFilename + ".csv")));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/comma-separated-values";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    }
```

Comment: Define `Popup` and show us the way you have outputted the CSV.

Comment: Show some code. How to you show the csv file?

Comment: Try using "text/csv" as the MIME type (Response.ContentType). I can't find any RFC for "text/comma-separated-values" (RFC 4180 is text/csv: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)

Answer (score 0):

just add a href with tartget="_new" pointing to your url from the web page.  If you need a popup withint he windows best option is to use a jquery pop libary they take externla url's.  If you are trying to use the native javascript popup this is a dialog box ment only for text ??

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Simon Thompson's answer (good answer simon).

I think your approaching this from the wrong side. A popup is not something created on the server side, instead it is something created on the client-side either in pure html or javascript.

So for example:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">open google in a popup</a>
```

Here is some more details about popup's: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

The quirksmode tutorial is a useful introduction, however to implement I would not use the approach and instead use a more "unobtrusive" approach (but i'd look into this later once you have a grasp of the popup fundamentals).